# Subversion, two repos, how to commit to a specific one?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository

Let's say I have a source directory and a build directory, and I need to commit the sources on one repository and the logs on a different one.

On Subversion documentation all I found is, basically:

```
$ svn checkout path/to/trunk ./
$ svn commit -m "Comment"
```

Is it possible to checkout two repositories at the same time, and commit to one of them only?

E.g.:

```
$ svn checkout path/to/trunk_src ./
$ svn checkout path/to/trunk_bin ./
$ cd ../src
$ svn commit -m "Comment" -toRepo src
$ cd ../bin
$ svn commit -m "Comment" -toRepo bin
```

where `-toRepo` does not exist but is what I need.

Would this be enough?

```
$ cd ../src
$ svn checkout path/to/trunk_src ./
$ svn commit -m "Comment"
$ cd ../bin
$ svn checkout path/to/trunk_bin ./
$ svn commit -m "Comment"
```

What about if the version control system is Git?

Comment: Do they have to be 2 different repositories? why not just do the whole thing in the same repository just under 2 different folders, then you could specify the path to the each folder when checking out the repository

Comment: Yes, they need to be two separate repositories.

Comment: If sources and logs are separated in tree into different repos - yes, you can. If no - yes, you still can in pure SVN, but… "with tricks"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible *[with SVN — added by phd]* to checkout two repositories at the same time, and commit to one of them only?

Subversion is a centralized VCS and can commit to one repo only. If you want to commit to two different repositories subdirectories `bin` and `src` must be 2 different checkouts from 2 different repos.

> What about if the version control system is Git?

Almost the same though for a different reason. With git you can push to as many repositories as you want. But you have to push the entire repo, you cannot push just one subdirectory. Hence subdirectories `bin` and `src` must again be 2 different checkouts from 2 different repos.

Comment: Wrong, RTFM "Externals" and "Submodules"

Comment: Submodules are definitely separate repositories.